# Is there an easy way to create a database diagram in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, diagram

I'm not sure if I have worded this question properly I will explain what I am trying to acheieve further.

I am looking to create a graphical representation of an existing database showing table relationships Key relationships etc.

I have seen posts around the internet that suggest you can just go; New > Database Diagram. But I have seen nothing to this effect in Management Studio

Something similar to this:

[image: Database diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to install the Diagram Support objects.  Then you all you expand the database out and right click the Database Diagram folder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If there is an database diagram drawn for the database it should be visible if you collapse DataBase Diagrams under your database. If you are trying to create one that is the way to go about it [create new database diagram](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1816).